# Help with FFmpeg keyframe command

Tags: video

I just discover FFmpeg, and I was using it to find keyframes.

I lost the command line due to the power outage.
I'm searching for a command line that produce the following output.
Can you help me with a command line that would generate this `test.txt` file?

> ```
> frame|key_frame=1|pkt_pts_time=1.441711|pict_type=I
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.483411|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.525122|pict_type=P
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.566833|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.608544|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.650244|pict_type=P
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.691956|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.733667|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.775378|pict_type=P
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.817078|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.858789|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.900500|pict_type=P
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.942211|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=1.983911|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=2.025622|pict_type=P
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=2.067333|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=2.109044|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=2.150744|pict_type=P
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=2.192456|pict_type=B
> frame|key_frame=0|pkt_pts_time=2.234167|pict_type=B
> ```

I have some of the command line, but it is not complete, so if anyone can help me to complete it, it would be much appreciated.

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.m2ts frame=key_frame,pkt_pts_time,pict_type (missing option directive ?) > file_output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -of compact -show_entries frame=key_frame,pkt_pts_time,pict_type INPUT_FILE > OUT
```

You can use `-sections` to get an overview of what information is available:

```
ffprobe -sections INPUT_FILE
```